# Chaining two functions in an event

Tags: mootools

I have this code, I'd like to make all a's `.ita`, `.eng`, `.rus` visible on hovering the `.all`. After `mouseleave`, I'd like to fade out the a's, and shrink back `.languages` to the size of just `.all`.

```html
<nav class="languages">
    <a href="#!" class="all">L</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/homepage" class="ita">ITA</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/en/homepage" class="eng">ENG</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/ru/homepage" class="rus">RUS</a>
</nav>
```

In the `mouseleave` event in the code below I would like to first tween the *languages* element, then bring the width of the container to 60px. Since it happens async, I cannot manage to see the fadeout of the element.

```coffeescript
$$('nav.languages').addEvents({
    'mouseenter': ->
        this.setStyle('width', "400px")
        languages.tween('opacity', 0, 1)
    , 'mouseleave': ->
        languages.tween('opacity', 1, 0)
        this.setStyle('width', "60px")
    })
```

I am reading about the **chain** method but it refers to a class, not an event, as I have understood.

Thanks

Comment: Could you share some HTML to understand better what you want to do? maybe you could use `el.set('tween', {onComplete: function(){`... like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10013934/2256325

Comment: Do you want to use `setStyle` or could it [also tween with opacity](http://jsfiddle.net/g6ynefhk/)? In that case [you could do it with CSS also](http://jsfiddle.net/g6ynefhk/1/).

Comment: Thanks Sergio I'm watching your two examples, very instructive!

Answer (score 2):

you can set `link: chain` to the instance of Fx.Tween

as for the rest, its more complex but something like this will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/d201npL2/1/

```
(function(){
    var languages = document.getElement('nav.languages span');
    languages.set('tween', {
        link: 'chain'
    });

    var nav = document.getElement('nav.languages').addEvents({
        'mouseenter:relay(a.all)': function(){
            nav.setStyle('width', 400);
            languages.fade(0, 1);
        }, 
        'mouseleave': function(){
            languages.fade(1, 0);
            this.setStyle('width', 60)
        }
    });
}());
```

you can do all this in pure CSS3, you know that, right?